# Accessing one view model from another

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a number of view models for various parts of my test application.

One view model is for User Settings (Default directory, SQL Server, SQL Database etc) called `MainSettingsViewModel`.  It contains an instance of the `MainSettings` model which contains configuration details.

Another view model contains a list of computers (with information like `ComputerName`, `ComputerDatabase`, Computer Sync Time etc) in an `ObservableCollection`.

Yet another contains details for Network Devices (Name, Location IP, etc).

Now I'll need to perform tasks using ALL the above information from these disparate view models.  For example, I want to ping each network device in the `NetworkDevices` view model and send the results to a file in the `MainSettings` view model and then communicate through each Computer view model and perform some tests.

The problem I'm experiencing is that these view models are constructed in their respective views and don't have any means to communicate their information with each other.

**How should my view models communicate with each other?**

Comment: I advice you reading more into MVVM pattern, before starting a project. You are obviously confusing the pattern with some object or base class, there is not "multiple MVVMs", you either have ViewModel, Model (as a layer or as an object) and View. "Model" also includes your business logic, i.e. services and repositories, not just POCO classes describing your data structure

Comment: Thanks Will and Tseng, terminology obviously makes a lot more sense when you word it like that. I will try and learn some more as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Each View Model will need a reference to any other View Models that it needs to communicate with

If you have a "Main" view model it can instantiate the other view models as it needs them, and pass a reference to its self in the constructor for them.  Those VMs can save that reference from the constructor in a private field and call public methods on it as needed.